# How to read dates (Birth) with google contacts service

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

Sorry for my poor english...
I try to read informations in my contacts with Google Apps Script - Contacts Service.

No problem with Name, Email, Adress, Phones, but I can't read dates (i want to get date of birth of my contacts).
How to read the "DateField"?

```
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
    Name = contacts[i].getFullName();

    EmailArray = contacts[i].getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL);
    if (EmailArray.length)
      Email = contacts[i].getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL)[0].getAddress();
    if (!Email){
      EmailArray = contacts[i].getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL);
      if (EmailArray.length)
        Email = contacts[i].getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL)[0].getAddress();
    }

    AddressArray = contacts[i].getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS);
    for ( var j = 0; j < AddressArray.length; j++ ) {
      Address = AddressArray[j].getAddress();
      AddressSplit = Address.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
      Rue = AddressSplit[0];
      Code = AddressSplit[1].split(" ")[0];
      Ville = AddressSplit[1].split(" ")[1];
    }

    var HomePhone = contacts[i].getHomePhone();
    var MobilePhone = contacts[i].getMobilePhone();

    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    DatesArray = contacts[i].getDates();
    // Never pass here... How to read the DateField ?
    for ( var j = 0; j < DatesArray.lenght; j++ ) {
      var date = contacts[i].getDates()[j];
      var day = date.getDay();
      var month = date.getMonth();
      var year = date.getYear();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution... after a moment !
Contacts services is not documented...

```
var dateArray = new Array(), day, month = new String, year;
var monthArray = ["0", "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];

dateArray = contacts[i].getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY);
for(var j in dateArray){
  day = dateArray[j].getDay();
  month = monthArray.indexOf(dateArray[j].getMonth().toString());
  year = dateArray[j].getYear();
  sheet.getRange(1*i+2, 3, 1, 1).setValue(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
DatesArray.length
```